# VPN setup multi-user multi-network topology

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, remote-access, wireguard

### Context

I am trying to understand how to best setup VPN access for a group of users and networks.
The situation is represented by this [network schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmn3w.png):

- `Site A` represents the main network

  - I have control over all devices in this network
  - The network is connected to the internet via `Router A`, which has a static public IP and a domain associated to it.
- `Site B` represents any external network (public, home, cellular hotspot...) a user of the main network might bring his device to and connect to the internet from.

  - I have no control on devices in this network, with the exception of the user device (e.g. `Endpoint B`)
  - We can assume `Router B` to be configured with dynamic IP, NAT and a firewall not allowing any non-established incoming connection
- `Site C` and `Site D` represent third-party networks which contain one ore more devices I control (`Endpoints C1`, `C2` and `D1`, `D2`)

  - These devices are connected among them via a switch
  - These devices are unmanned, which should be accessible 24/7 without requiring local intervention
  - One of these devices per network (`Edpoint C1` for `Site C` and `Endpoint D1` for `Site D`) is connected to the internet via the router.
  - We can assume the router is configured with dynamic IP, NAT  and a firewall not allowing any non-established incoming connection.
  - Devices on different secondary networks can (and will) be configured to use the same subnet (e.g. endpoints in `Site C` and `Site D` both use `192.168.254.0/24`) with possible IP conflicts between networks, requiring them to be kept separate

Endpoints are mainly Linux (especially the ones in the secondary networks), but there are also some windows clients.

### Objectives

I'd like to reach the following objectives (hopefully with a single solution, but if it's not possible, separate solutions are ok as well):

1. Authorized clients connected outside the main network (`Endpoint B`) should be able to connect to it (e.g. to communicate with the `NAS`).
2. Authorized clients connected either inside (`Endpoint A1`) or outside the main network (`Endpoint B`) should be able to connect to secondary network (`Site C` or `Site D`)

   - Each use is authorized to connect to certain secondary networks, not necessary all of them (e.g. `User 1` can connect to `Site C` and `Site D`, while `User 2` can connect to `Site D` only).
   - Authorization depends on the user (i.e. on the device) and not where the device is conencted from (e.g. `User 2` can connect to `Site D` from `Site A` or from `Site B`).
   - A single user can be authorized to access one or more secondary network, but will only connect to one at a time
   - Multiple users must be able to be connected to the same secondary network at the same time
   - (de)authorizing users to connect to a particular secondary network (e.g. `Site D`) should not require any intervention on the devices in the secondary network itself (e.g. `Endpoints D1`, `D2`)

### Solution ideas

I think point 1 is easily solved with any VPN which allows point-to-site connection: I am woring to setup Wireguard on `Host A` with port forwarding from `Router A` and as far as I understood, this should be enough to reach my first objective.

Instead, I am a bit stuck on how to tackle point 2. The ideas I am exploring are:

- using `Host A` exposed via `Router A` (or directly an external dedicated VPS) as the center of a hub and spoke layout. All endpoints would be able to connect to it since it would have a public IP.
- wireguard's persistent keepalive option should let the endpoints in the secondary networks poke through the NAT, maintaining the connection to `Host A`
- `Host A` would be running one wireguard NIC for every secondary network, each mapped to a different port, with IP forwarding from the physical NIC to each wireguard NIC
- A different configuration must be generated for any user-network couple that I want to authorize (as well as one for the endpoint in the secondary network)
- Each user would then be able to connect to a specific port on `Host A`, and thus to a specific secondary network

I am not sure about the the correctness or the specifics of these last parts: is this a good way to go? Is there a better way? Would switching to another software (e.g. openVPN) make it easier?
If this is the way to go, is there any software that eases the management of the multiple interfaces and users credentials?
I am mainly looking for free solutions, possibly open source/self-hosted.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who is going to chime in, even with the smallest indication!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using WireGuard is an excellent way to approach this problem.

As you suggested, you could use Host A as a central hub for your network (or set up a dedicated hub on some other host with a public IP address); and WireGuard's persistent keepalive option will allow inbound connections to be tunneled to other clients that connect to it (eg C1, D1, etc).

You don't necessarily need multiple NICs on Host A, however -- all your need is one physical NIC (the NIC it uses to connect to the Internet, like `eth0`), and one WireGuard virtual network interface (eg `wg0`). Each device in your WireGuard network will send encrypted packets to the hub through the hub's physical NIC, and the hub will decrypt those packets and re-queue them as incoming packets for its WireGuard interface. As each packet emerges from the WireGuard interface, you apply standard firewall and routing rules to determine what to do with the packet (usually to send it back through the WireGuard interface, to be re-encrypted and sent to another device).

This is what you can do:

1. Come up with one or more private-use address blocks to dedicate to your WireGuard network. For example, say you decide to use `10.100.0.0/24` for user devices, and `10.200.0.0/20` for non-user devices. (If all your devices and everything they need to access fully supports IPv6, you may want to just use IPv6 addresses to avoid address-space collisions.)
2. Assign an IP address from the appropriate address block from #1 to each device, and use that IP address as the `AllowedIPs` setting for the device in the hub's WireGuard configuration. (For non-user devices, also include the other virtual address space that can be accessed through the device in the `AllowedIPs` setting.)
3. In the WireGuard configuration on each individual device, use the assigned IP address from #2 as its `Address` setting (and specify *all* your WireGuard address blocks in the device's `AllowedIPs` setting pointing back to the hub).
4. Set up a bunch of firewall rules on the hub to implement your user-authorization business logic, using the IP addresses assigned from #2 to uniquely identify each device. (WireGuard will ensure that for each configured peer of an interface, packets decrypted with the peer's configured public key *must* have a source address matching the peer's configured `AllowedIPs` setting -- otherwise the packet will be dropped. Therefore, with any firewall rules that are applied to a packet incoming from a WireGuard interface, you can be sure that the packet came from the specific device that has an `AllowedIPs` setting matching the packet's source address.)
5. To provide access to conflicting address space (eg to allow access to the `192.168.254.0/24` LAN subnets in both Site C and Site D), have your WireGuard devices use different addresses from your dedicated WireGuard address space for each such conflict, and use NAT on the WireGuard devices that act as gateways to the conflicting subnets to translate from your WireGuard address space to the actual LAN addresses.

   For example, you might use `10.200.2.0/24` as the virtual address space for the `192.168.254.0/24` subnet in Site C, and `10.200.3.0/24` as the virtual address space for the `192.168.254.0/24` subnet in Site D. On Endpoint C1 (your WireGuard gateway to Endpoint C2), use NAT to translate `10.200.2.2` to `192.168.254.2`; and on the hub, route `10.200.2.0/24` to Endpoint C1. If a user using Endpoint B navigates to `http://10.200.2.2/` in a web browser, that request will be routed through your WireGuard network to Endpoint C1, and Endpoint C1 can translate and route the request appropriately to Endpoint C2.

As a concrete example, with two devices -- Endpoint B as a user device for User 3, and Endpoint C1 with say an SSH server running on it, plus providing access to the virtual `10.200.2.0/24` network -- the hub's WireGuard config might look like this:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

# local settings for Host A
[Interface]
PrivateKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEE=
Address = 10.200.0.1
ListenPort = 51820

# remote settings for Endpoint B
[Peer]
PublicKey = fE/wdxzl0klVp/IR8UcaoGUMjqaWi3jAd7KzHKFS6Ds=
AllowedIPs = 10.100.1.3

# remote settings for Endpoint C1
[Peer]
PublicKey = jUd41n3XYa3yXBzyBvWqlLhYgRef5RiBD7jwo70U+Rw=
AllowedIPs = 10.200.1.1, 10.200.2.0/24
```

And the WireGuard config for Endpoint B (User 3's device) might look like this:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

# local settings for Endpoint B
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBFA=
Address = 10.100.1.3

# remote settings for Host A
[Peer]
PublicKey = /TOE4TKtAqVsePRVR+5AA43HkAK5DSntkOCO7nYq5xU=
Endpoint = 5.5.5.5:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.100.0.0/24, 10.200.0.0/20
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

And the WireGuard config for Endpoint C1 might look like this:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

# local settings for Endpoint C1
[Interface]
PrivateKey = CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCGA=
Address = 10.200.1.1

# remote settings for Host A
[Peer]
PublicKey = /TOE4TKtAqVsePRVR+5AA43HkAK5DSntkOCO7nYq5xU=
Endpoint = 5.5.5.5:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.100.0.0/24, 10.200.0.0/20
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

You might use an nftables ruleset like the following on the hub to accept WireGuard connections from your devices, and to implement your user-authorization rules:

```
table inet filter {
    # put all your user-authorization rules here
    chain device-access-policies {
        # allow User 3 to access SSH on Endpoint C1
        ip saddr 10.100.1.3 ip daddr 10.200.1.1 tcp dport 22 accept
        # allow User 3 to access webserver on Endpoint C2
        ip saddr 10.100.1.3 ip daddr 10.200.2.2 tcp dport 80 accept
        # deny everything else
        reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited
    }

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        iif "lo" accept
        ct state vmap { invalid : drop, established : accept, related : accept }
        iifname "eth0" udp dport 51820 accept
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
        ct state vmap { invalid : drop, established : accept, related : accept }
        iifname "wg0" goto device-access-policies
    }
}
```

And on Endpoint C1, you might have an nftables ruleset like the following to blindly accept and forward everything the hub sends to it, and to NAT the virtual `10.200.2.0/24` address space to its local `192.168.254.0/24` subnet:

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        iif "lo" accept
        ct state vmap { invalid : drop, established : accept, related : accept }
        iifname "wg0" accept
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
        ct state vmap { invalid : drop, established : accept, related : accept }
        iifname "wg0" accept
    }
}
table inet nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;
        ip daddr 10.200.2.0/24 dnat ip prefix to 192.168.254.0/24
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        iifname "wg0" masquerade
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is much more detailed than I hoped.
I tried it out and it looks like everything works as intended: I only had to expand Host A's configs borrowing from Endpoint C's to include the nat towards the primary network (since Host A behaves both as a hub and as a network ingress point)